# Unknown 2-pin weatherproof connector

Tags: connector, low-voltage

We have a meteorological station (Made by the now-defunct Solar Millennium) next to our solar plant that has a faulty connector from its PV panel. It has a circular cross section and has a screw-in weatherproof housing. What is this connection called and where can I find one. Please see the enclosed photographs.
[image: End-on view of the unknown connector]

[image: The unknown connector (right-most connector)]

Comment: Please show a photo that has a ruler scale next to the connector.  We simply don't know how large the connector is.  One suggestion - have a look at the Amp (part of Tyco Electronics) CPC series.  That connector looks very similar to connectors that we have used in the past.

Comment: http://canada.newark.com/amp-te-connectivity/206425-1/circular-connector-receptacle/dp/46F1145

Comment: Check also Amphenol and Souriau. Both sell similar connectors. They come in different shell sizes (8, 10, 12 etc) Different pin configurations and locking mechanisms (Bayonet, threaded)